# configure shell in pycharm odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, odoo, odoo-10

Good afternoon friends, I have installed pycharm in windows 10 and I am working with odo and it works great. now I do not know how to configure in (parameters) the odoo shell to be able to perform ORM functions.

in this way I did not apply in the windows console and open the shell but in pychar I do not know how to do it.

```
In version 10: ./odoo-bin shell -d <database>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In odoo directory which holds the odd-bin file type in the terminal

```
python odoo-bin shell -d <name_of_the_database>
```

the name of the database should be intialized from odoo database manager